# .vimrc not apply during ssh

Tags: vim, ssh

I'm connecting two computers using ssh.
I have .vimrc file saved in both computers.
However, it seems like the .vimrc in remote computer does not apply when logged in using ssh.
The system in remote computer is Ubuntu 10.10.
Any one knows how to solve fix this problem?
thanks.

Comment: Is the .vimrc for both machines in the homefolder for the account you are using?

Comment: What does the output of "`:scriptnames`" show?